# Wordpress conditional permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a specific page on my wordpress website `example.com/download/` that I already have a page for. I would like to add some sort of php code to enable the following functionality.

- If there is a subpath after the `/download/<name>`, I would like to fetch a file from some directory based on `<name>`
- If no subpath is specified (`/download/`) I want to display the page that is already written

Is this possible with Wordpress hooks/filters?

I have a feeling it has something to do with the WP_Rewrite class, but I am not sure exactly what to write, nor where to put it without WP or theme updates wiping the code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to add a custom rewrite rule. You can use your theme's functions.php to add the new functionality.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^download\/([^/]+)\/?','your_url_to_the_downloader_file.php?download=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

To make it work, first you need to go to `Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks` and click the save button so the new rule is added.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Just tried to incorporate this. I got an error `function custom_rewrite_rule() { add_rewrite_rule('^download\/([^/]+)\/?','/wp-content/download_content/$matches[1]','top'); } add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/20/10282520/html/wp-content/themes/theme-child/functions.php:4) in /home/content/20/10282520/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1203`

Comment: Never mind. Total typo. Thats what I get for late night programming with no coffee :)